# Datagidview update to DB mysql error "" concurrency violation: the updatecommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records""

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

How to update DB from Datagridview c# ?  My project is work for load data table in DB.but can't update into DB

It's load data button

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connectionString;

        connectionString = "Server=localhost;User Id=root; Password=1234; Database=db2; Pooling=false;CharSet=tis620;";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from data Where Id = '" + comp.Text.Trim() + "'", connection);

        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        Table1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

and update button

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        cmdbl = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sda);

        sda.Update(dt);//error" concurrency violation: the updatecommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records"
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Save data complete");

}
```

I follow this clip [Insert,Delete and Update data in database from datagridview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sB0A6FIhUM)
and i can't do it 
Sorry for my english I speak not good enough   and thank you for answer.and final i get error" concurrency violation: the updatecommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Update Query? Make sure that along with the "Select" query you have an "Update" written

Comment: sdaUpdateCmd = New SqlCommand("Update CustTest set CustName = @pCustName where CustId = @pCustId", da.SelectCommand.Connection)

Comment: Then set your update command for sda to your new variable like this

Comment: Did you fix your problem